# how would I make a brightness level option?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

In Blender, how would I make a brightness level option, what would be the best way to make something like this? Concept design below:

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to change the brightness of . . ?

Comment: of a blender game in BGE the brightness of the application i am making example i have a little interface ive built it has an  options menu and i want to make a birghtness button that changes the brightness level of  the background or 3d scene if all this helps you understand better

Comment: that does not help -_-

Comment: Honestly I am not sure how you would achieve this . . . changing lamp strength won't really do it, fading materials will just wash it out . . . dimming the display is really the only way :-P

Comment: hey i did not even think about the lamps,wonder if there is a way to increase strength of a lamp by a button?  i may haft to ask this question in a different way on a new question...

Comment: Maybe a simple post processing filter? Or mixing in some shadeless-ness?